# Redirecting html page with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have a combo-box which redirects a user to a specific page. To redirect, if I use

```
window.location.href = ...
```

when they hit back, it automatically redirects again. And if I use

```
window.location.replace (...)
```

they can't go back, because the history gets replaced with the new page.

I would have thought it's a fairly common scenario, so just wanted to ask if anyone knows a trick I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: try just window.location and see

Comment: where is window.location.href = called?  onLoad?  onChange?

Comment: it's called in a jquery callback function after user chooses an item in the drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

just check position of your syntax.
put it inside some function or event.
use below syntax : 
    window.location = "your_url";

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally figured it out.
Turns out the jquery MultiSelect I'm using seems to preserve it's value so when I go 'back' into the browse, the MultiSelect kicks off an event as though it's been selected, which kicks off the redirect :( 
Fixed now by clearing the selected item and then redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the onchange event of the select so the redirect wont happen until a user updates the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script language='javascript'>window.location='index.php'</script>
```

it works...

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. Before you do window.location.url, do like:

```
if (!window.flag) window.location.url
window.flag=true;
```

So after you instructed for redirect, you are resetting the flag. So when you hit back button on the new page, it goes to the old page, but doesn't redirect.